# Issues with the rendered HTML code coming through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following html code:

```
<div id="contentProductDetails" style="display:none;">
      <table align="center" width="100%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="2" class="table-responsive">
        <tr>
          <th>ItemName</th>
          <th>Qty</th>
          <th>Tracking Number</th>
          <th>Discount Offered</th>
          <th>Unit Price</th>
          <th>Unit Cost</th>
          <th>Profit</th>
          <th>Category</th>
          <th>Supplier Name</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
                <div class="adddynamicdata"></div>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

in the tbody, i have a dynamic div, which is showing the data coming in the `tr` and `td`'s.

The issue is the div is appearing at the top while in the place where i am trying to display it:

here is my ajax

```
$("#findproduct").bind('keydown change focusout blur', function(e) {
        $('#loading').show().html('Loading...');
        var data = $('#findproduct').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "findproduct.cfm?term="+data,
            data: data,
            success: function (msg) {
                $("#contentProductDetails").css('display','block');
                $('.adddynamicdata').append(msg);
                $('#loading').hide(); 
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: You can't stick a `div` within a `tbody` tag. The browser is helping out by fixing the mess and putting it outside there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="adddynamicdata"></div>
```

is not part of Table.. so it will be displayed outside of table..

if your dynamic data is simple text then use this

```
 <tbody>
    <tr><td class="adddynamicdata"></td></tr>
 </tbody>
```

or if your data is tableRows then use this

```
 <tbody class="adddynamicdata">

 </tbody>
```